# Populate & Clear Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have followed the Google Maps API v3 tutorial for creating a basic map.  I'm trying to figure out how to declare the map initially and then allow me to add points based on the "category" that people select.  I'm also trying to figure out how to clear the map in between each selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a form field for category.  Changing that triggers a JS function which clears all markers from the map, then adds some on for that category.  If you expand on your question with what code you've tried so far I could expand this answer.

To clear markers, use `marker.setMap(null);` on each one (there's no API function that will clear them all for you).

You probably also want a JS array or associative-array of categories with data for each marker (at least lat/lng values), which will make it easy for your function.

Ok, here's a working solution (I've reduced the amount of markers etc for brevity).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550211/populate-clear-google-map/15550488?noredirect=1#comment22037226_15550488</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map-canvas { width:600px; height:500px }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var MSU;
    var map;
    var BusRouteButton = document.getElementById('Add-Bus-Route');

    var arrRoutes = [
        {
            name : "Mustang",
            color : "#660000",
            route : [
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.87528, -98.51848),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.87045, -98.51856),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.86926, -98.51844),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.86666, -98.51833),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.86503, -98.51849),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.87529, -98.52366),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.87524, -98.52195),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.87521, -98.52026),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.87528, -98.51848)
            ],
            stops : [
                [33.87262, -98.51856],
                [33.86503, -98.51849],
                 [33.87529, -98.52366]
            ],
            markers : []
        },
        {
            name : "Foobar",
            color : "#000066",
            route : [
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.87528, -98.51848),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.87524, -98.52195),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.86926, -98.51844),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(33.87184, -98.52376)
            ],
            stops : [
                [33.87528, -98.51848],
                [33.87184, -98.52376]
            ],
            markers : []
        }
    ];

    function initialize() {
        MSU = new google.maps.LatLng(33.87356, -98.52130);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: MSU,
            zoom: 16,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        // lets add the data from the array to the page!  I'm going to use jQuery's append for this, you could also use document.write if you aren't using it
        for (var i = 0; i < arrRoutes.length; i++) {
            $('#category').append(
                '<option value="' + i + '">' + arrRoutes[i].name + '</option>'
            );
        }
    }


    function BusRouteMarkers() {
            // what's the currently selected category?
            var intRoute = $('#category').val();

            for (var i = 0; i < arrRoutes.length; i++) {
                // better get rid of any previous polylines first
                if (arrRoutes[i].polyline) {
                    arrRoutes[i].polyline.setMap(null);
                }

                // ditto for any previous markers
                for (var j = 0; j < arrRoutes[i].markers.length; j++) {         
                    arrRoutes[i].markers[j].setMap(null);
                }
            }

            // add this polyline to the array for reference later
            arrRoutes[intRoute].polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                 path: arrRoutes[intRoute].route,
                 strokeColor: arrRoutes[intRoute].color,
                 strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                 strokeWeight: 4,
                map: map
            });


            for (var i = 0; i < arrRoutes[intRoute].stops.length; i++) {
                arrRoutes[intRoute].markers.push(
                    new google.maps.Marker({ 
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                            arrRoutes[intRoute].stops[i][0], 
                            arrRoutes[intRoute].stops[i][1]
                        ), 
                        map: map 
                    })
                );
            }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<button id="Add-Bus-Route" onClick="BusRouteMarkers()">click me</button>

<select id="category">
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I have setup so far for my js.  As for the array, I have a json array of all my points with the category they belong to.

I'm working on an interactive bus route for a class project and I'm using my university as an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/maddtechwf/2BpJH/

Comment: ok, so I would say you want one big array for all the routes.  Use this array to create multiple bus routes corresponding to which category the user selects.  I'll try and get back to you with some code for this.

Comment: What all would I need to do to create an array for Markers only?  I have a new array declared just not sure what items are suppose to into it(ex. name, color, route, etc...).